# Открытие меню в приложении как tabItem WPF

Tags: wpf, меню

Возникла необходимость создать следующую структуру приложения на WPF:

1) При открытии приложения отображается пустое окно в котором есть только меню сверху.

2) При выборе любого пункта в меню открывать в окне приложения нужную вкладку как tabItem. Между вкладками можно переключаться.

3) Можно открыть любое количество одинаковых вкладок и тогда они нумеруются, пример: Вкладка файла 2, вкладка файла 2 1, вкладка файла 2 2, вкладка файла 2 3 и т.д.

Может кто такое уже разрабатывал и подскажет (или покажет) как такое можно реализовать?

**Пример** того что нужно получить нарисованный в паинте**:**

[image: Пример как должно выглядеть приложение со вкладками]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Proof of concept]

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CommandMenuItemStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        <Setter Property="Command"
                Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CommandMenuItemStyle}" />
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ICommand _menuCommand;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _menuCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(title =>
       {
           if (!TabItems.Contains(title))
           {
               TabItems.Add(title);
           }
       });
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>
        {
            new MenuItem {Title = "Item1", Command = _menuCommand},
            new MenuItem {Title = "Item2", Command = _menuCommand},
            new MenuItem {Title = "Item3", Command = _menuCommand},
        };
        TabItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> TabItems { get; set; }
}
```